# how to prevent null reference exception when doing a linear search of array?

Tags: c#

Hi I'm doing a beginners course C# and trying to prevent a nulllreference exception when searching in an array

I've made a small program which takes user string input and places it in an array. the array is also searchable through a menu but if I choose "search array" before there are anything added to the array, the program crashes during a null reference exception. Is there any way around this using tryparse?

```
switch (selection)
{
    case 1://for loop för att lägga till grejer, stuff.length; ger att du kan lägga till 5 saker 
        for (int i = 0; i < stuff.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Lägg till ett föremål: ");
            stuff[i] += Console.ReadLine();
        }
        break;
    case 2://for loop som skriver ut innehåll
        for (int i = 0; i < stuff.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(stuff[i]);
        }
        break;
    case 3://linjär sökning av innehåll
        Console.Write(" skriv in ett sökord");
        string searchword = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < stuff.Length; i++)
            {
                if (stuff[i].ToUpper() == searchword.ToUpper())
                    Console.WriteLine("vi hittade" + stuff[i]);
            }
        break;
    case 4://bryter loopen och programmet avslutas
        isRunning = false;
        break;
```

Comment: format your code

Comment: Sorry about that, new to stackoverflow, hopefully the formatting is better now

Comment: `stuff[i] += Console.ReadLine()`, why `+=`?

Comment: @snabelhund: I've fixed it now - but it's worth using the preview when writing and editing.

Comment: for adding strings to the array, is there a better way?

Comment: The code you  posted I do not think will give any exceptions.  Can you indicate the line where the exception is occurring and the exact exception message you are getting?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you, I'm really new to this, so i apologize if I'm doing things the wrong way.

Comment: @jdweng This code won't throw provided case 1 is executed before cases 2 and 3 but will if it's not the case

Comment: @jdweng if i choose case 3 and enter a search word i get a                                        "system.nullreferenceexception" at the line 21

Comment: @snabelhund You need to make sure, that your stuff array always has values. Right now it's only populated after case 1 hase been executed. But if it hasn't, you try to access a void. Which throws the exception.

Comment: @vc74 i guess there s a better way than     stuff[i]+=Console.ReadLine() what would be a better way of doing it?

Comment: @snabelhund It depends on what you want to achieve, if you just want to store what the user has typed: `stuff[i] = Console.ReadLine()` but if you want to concatenate the current string with what the user has typed, your code is correct (if you check for nulls)

Comment: @vc74 Thank you. Sorry for poor formatting from my side.

Comment: Also should i upvote or do something, whats the etiquette here on stack overflow? Sorry for newbie questions.

Comment: @snabelhund No worries, you're learning... (and you had the great honor of being edited by Jon Skeet!). If you think one of the answers below answers your question you can accept it and optionally upvote it.

Comment: @vc74 Thanks, if i have different question regarding my code should i make a new post or edit this one?

Comment: If these questions are not related to this one, yes, create a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, I think you just want to initialize the items with what the user has typed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stuff.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Lägg till ett föremål: ");
    stuff[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you use `+=` (to concatenate the current item with the user entry), an exception will be thrown if `stuff[i]` is null.

In case 3, you have to check whether an item is null:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stuff.Length; i++)
{
    if (stuff[i]?.ToUpper() == searchword.ToUpper())
        Console.WriteLine("vi hittade" + stuff[i]);
}
```

Note that both issues would be fixed if you created the array this way:

```
string[] stuff = Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, 200).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable.Where()` to find all matching elements using predicate and loop through it using `ForEach` to display items..

```
   case 3://linjär sökning av innehåll
                            Console.Write(" skriv in ett sökord");
                            string searchword = Console.ReadLine();
                            var lstElementsFound = stuff.Where(x => x.ToUpper() == searchword.ToUpper());
                            foreach (var item in stuff)
                            {
                              Console.WriteLine("vi hittade" + item);
                            }

                            break;
```

Don't forget to import `System.Linq`.